# Git only commit files from one folder

Tags: git

I have a project with multiple folders and I would like to only commit the files in one folder.

However, I do not want to checkout the the other files (since I am still working on them).

I was wondering if there was a way to do this with `git commit` or if I need to `git stash` the other files and then commit normally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git commit path/to/files/* -m"Message"
```

Will only commit only those files under path/to/files, ignoring other files in the staging area.

Comment: i got it to work by going to the folder and running `git commit --only  .`

Answer (score 1):

Add only the files you want to commit to the index, than commit.

```
git add -u subdir_to_commit
git commit
```

You can view what's currently in the index and what not with:

```
git status
```

Comment: yeah but the problem was that those files (in other folders) were already tracked with relevant changes

Comment: Doesn't matter if git tracks them or not, just if you added the files to the index or not.

Comment: Oh, so you already pushed some (but not all) of your changes through to the index and wouldn't want to commit it? And your working directory was different from what you had in the index and you wanted to preserve both?

Comment: The problem is that I am using an eclipse plugin in conjunction with cmd line (with which I commit) so I got into a state where I had not files in my index that I had been working on that were not ready for commit as well as the files I wanted to commit